# Where can I extract the unperturbed prediction residuals without undergoing transform and quantization in the HM encoder?

Tags: global-variables, prediction, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

Should I use a global variable to save the residuals before the transform stage in the HM encoder, or subtract the original image from m_ppcPredYuvBest

but I noticed that the values of m_ppcPredYuvBest at the edges of the image when CTU is not 64x64 do not match the values in the output bitstream?

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem is vague.

- Are we talking about the encoder or the decoder, or both? If both, do precise it.
- Output bitstream does not include prediction signal. Do you mean the prediction signal that you get during the decoding process of the output bitstream? If so, what are you comparing it to? Is it the prediction signal during the encoding?

Clarify these aspect and we might be able to propose a solution.

Eventually, I'd most likely suggest that you look for the residual buffer during the encoding. A buffer that is computed during the RDO and is still accessible during the encoding (CABAC stuff). Something like the prediction buffer that have found. I don't have access to code right now, but if such buffer does not exist already, I believe you can create it with a reasonably small effort. And that would be mimicking all the code related prediction buffer, including 3 main steps of 1) initialisation, 2) setting and updating values during the RDO and 3) destroying the buffer (to avoid memory leak)